# AngularJs, What is better when creating a controller?

Tags: angularjs

What is better when creating a controller in AngularJs:

1-

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('MyController',['$scope','dependencies','myService', function($scope, dependencies, myService ) {

}]);
```

2-

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('MyController', function($scope, dependencies, myService ) {

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance wise, the first is technically better, although that cost is probably negligible. If you do it the second way, angular literally calls the .toString() function on your controller function, and then parses the string to determine the dependencies. So you can either declare them yourself, or angular will parse your function as a string to determine them.

As a developer, I find it easier to read and write the second version. Just be aware that you have to change things to the first form if you plan on uglifying/minifying your code. Some tools will do this for you automatically (ngAnnotate, for example), so that you can write it the 2nd way, but have it deployed the first way.

Comment: "Just be aware that you have to change things to the first form"  can u please explain more what things?

Comment: By "change things" I meant change all of your dependency injection syntax to the first form if you plan on uglifying/minifying your javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

With this method you have the advantage of function hoisting , function name for debugging , ability to mutate $inject;
also easier to reason about & debugging.

```js
function myController(){
  
}
myController.$inject = ['$scope','dependencies','myService'];
angular.module('myApp' ,myController);
```